# TypeScript Decorators - Setter not called on property of an object

Tags: angular, typescript, decorator

I am trying to implement TypeScript Decorators for storing data in localstorage in an Angular app. This is what I am trying to achieve

```
export function Cache() {

    return function (target, key): any {
        // property value
        let _val = target[key];

        // property getter
        const getter = function () {
            const data = localStorage.get(key);
            if (data) {
                return data;
            }
            localStorage.set(key, _val);
            return _val;
        };

        // property setter
        const setter = function (newVal) {
            localStorage.set(key, newVal);
            console.log('Setting',newVal);
            _val = newVal;
        };

        // Create new property with getter and setter
        Object.defineProperty(target, key, {
            configurable: true,
            enumerable: true,
            get: getter,
            set: setter
        });
    };
}
```

And use it like:
Component 1:

```
....
@Cache() userSession: any = {val:''};

ngOnInit() {
    this.userSession.val = "some val"
  }
....
```

Component 2:

```
....
@Cache() userSession: any;

ngOnInit() {
    console.log('Stored value is',this.userSession);
    // expected : {val:'some val'}
    // prints : {val:''}
}
....
```

So from what I understand, the property setter is called only when there is any assignment to the object itself and not it's property. Hence this works,

```
Object.assign(this.userSession , {val: 'some val'});
or
this.userSession = {val: 'some val'}

console.log(this.userSession) // prints: {val: 'some val'}
```

But this will kind of beat the purpose I am trying to achieve here. So the question is, how do I modify the decorator function to be able to do this?

```
this.userSession.val = 'some val';
```

Any pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using decorators in this way, but I'm pretty sure you need to delete the property in order to replace it, so change this:

```
    Object.defineProperty(target, key, {
        get: getter,
        set: setter,
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true
    });
```

To this (wrapping with a delete):

```
if (delete this[key]) {
    Object.defineProperty(target, key, {
        get: getter,
        set: setter,
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true
    });
}
```

Comment: That's not the issue. There is no need to delete the existing property if present. In this case it isn't even present. The issue is that the access is nested.